# How to use Calculate Function in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I am new to PowerPivot and tried to use Calculation(). However, no matter I change, it always showing Error. 
I had sum the Total Sales, just want to calculate the sales for Peak time. Therefore, my formula is as following:

```
Peak:=Calculate([Total Sales],[Period]="Peak")
```

Could you please let me know why it shows error? Do I miss something?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the error message is along the following for a calculated measure

> Calculation error in measure 'Table1'[Test]: The value for 'period'
>   cannot be determined. Either 'period' doesn't exist, or there is no
>   current row for a column named 'period'.

It would be due to not referencing the column name in the table you are filtering against.

```
Test:=CALCULATE( [Total Sales], Table1[period] = "Peak")
```